# .NET SqlParameter Class: will it truncate .Value string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Using the example from the .NET documentation:

```
private static void AddSqlParameter(SqlCommand command, string paramValue)
{
    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 88);
    parameter.IsNullable = true;
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    parameter.Value = paramValue;

    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
```

If the corresponding stored procedure has `DECLARE @Description varchar(100)` and the table itself has the column `Description` set to `VARCHAR(100)`, what happens when the `paramValue` is 100 characters long?  Does the `SqlParameter.Value` truncate before binding/executing the SQL Server stored procedure?

Comment: try it yourself and see. If no exception is thrown then it truncates it. Or else you will see the sql exception about string will be truncated

Comment: It is likely to be on a provider basis.  I know the SQLite provider does not truncate strings, but it can throw an exception for values out of range

Comment: Why would you assign a value to an ouput?

Comment: Man, harsh on here; why the downvote?

Comment: @Steve for some pseudo-political reasons, I can't right now.  I could set it up in another environment I guess if no one knows the answer.  Docs don't say one way or the other though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So whether or not this precisely answers your question, here's what I found.

The `SqlParameter` object holds the full length string (even though you've specified it's 88 characters long). This makes sense because if it didn't and you went and changed that after the fact, you would have lost data. Plus, that's unnecessary overhead for C# to manage, so I'd be surprised if such truncation was put in voluntarily.

Looking at the query plan though, the ParameterCompiledValue is the truncated version. So it's happening somewhere between there (I would guess when the SqlClient library translates the SqlCommand object into an actual TSQL statement to run against the database).

So nothing blows up if your application is more restrictive than the database. But it *will* respect the size limit you impose on the SqlParameter, regardless of what the database could reasonably hold.

Answer (score 1):

It truncates if you specify the size Property of the SqlParamater object; which you have done (88).

SqlParameter.Size Property

> Definition
> Namespace:
> System.Data.SqlClient
> Assembly:
> System.Data.SqlClient.dll
> Gets or sets the maximum size, in bytes, of the data within the column....
>
> ...(if) the parameter value is greater than the size, then the value will be truncated to match the size

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0